# How should we format text?

Tags: discusión, formato

I was going through [a question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2593/1674) and saw that the formatting was a bit difficult to follow:

---

In the example "Te veo los ojos", in English that is "I see your eyes". te=your, right? If I change the sentence to "Se veo los ojos", then it will become "I see his/her/its/your eyes"? Are these two sentences missing the subjects?

---

I changed it to `"format"` because, to me, it looks quite easier to read:

---

In the example `"Te veo los ojos"`, in English that is `"I see your eyes"`. `te=your`, right? If I change the sentence to `"Se veo los ojos"`, then it will become `"I see his/her/its/your eyes"`? Are these two sentences missing the subjects?

---

But then I wondered: do we have a canonical way to do this? Going through Meta I could not find any specific answer about this specific case of quotes within a sentence.

I think it would be good setting it.

Here is the options we have (feel free to suggest / edit with more):

- "quoting"
- **"quoting and bolding"**
- `coding`
- **`coding and bolding`**
- `"double quoting"`
- **`"quoting, coding and bolding"`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I meant to do this proposal a while ago, but here goes based on how I've been doing my answers and I think a lot of others have as well.

For bilingual answers (where we've translated them), I recommend putting the language of the response using the markup `### English`

With the following result:

> #### English
>
> And now we begin an answer in English
>
> #### Spanish
>
> Y la repetimos en castellano.

When quoting, there's no real strict standard difference between quotation marks, italics, or blockquote, but I'd propose the following:

- Quotation marks (either «», “”, or ‘’): quoting of actual sources elsewhere that are brief (one-two lines at most).
- Blockquote: (using `>`) any quotation that is going to be longer, or that requires complex formatting.  In these cases, especially in the case of a definition from a dictionary or an example from a grammar like the Nueva Gramática, we ought to use the first line to cite it, and then after a newline, cite the actual text.
- Italics: when we are using words or short phrases as entities.  For example, “In the phrase *me gusta nadar*, the subject is *nadar*.”  If a sentence, and used as in isolation (cast off by a colon, for instance), blockquote may be better.  In any case, we should probably uphold standard linguistic symbology (unless context makes it incredibly clear) for these phrases as well which would be:

  - *me gusta correr* (correct, unmarked)
  - **Tú hablan español* (wrong)
  - <sup>?</sup>*No creo que es así.* (dubious, <sup>??</sup> for very dubious)
  - <sup>%</sup>*La arena es blanco* (grammatical only in some dialects).
  - For answers oriented towards beginners, it may be useful to instead using the `<sub></sub>` to make these things explicit.  E.g., *me gusta correr* <sub>(correct)</sub>, but *Tú hablan español* <sub>(incorrect)</sub>

When answer, the primary answer should go in **bold**.  For example, if someone wants to know what the superlative of *pobre* is, the answer would look like the following:

> The word *pobrísimo* doesn't exist, a lot of adjectives that have an *l* or *r* in the final syllable have irregular forms.  So the correct superlative of *pobre* is **paupérrimo**.

This way someone scanning the question and the answer can quickly locate the answer. (notice I didn't write **pobrísimo* because context makes it clear it's wrong)

I also tend to use bold if I have a list of things that require long explanations

> There are a number of different stem changes possible in Spanish, but only three of them are common:
>
> - **o→ue**
>   The explanation for *o* to *ue* changes will take more than a single line so it doesn't make much sense for us to use superscript or subscript annotations as those aren't pretty when they have a line break.
> - **e→ie**
>   Likewise here the next one would need to be very long and break the line so visually this looks better.
> - **e→i**
>   Likewise here the next one would need to be very long and break the line so visually this looks better.
> - **i→ie**
>   Likewise here the next one would need to be very long and break the line so visually this looks better.
> - **u→ue**
>   Likewise here the next one would need to be very long and break the line so visually this looks better.

But there are times that superscript can look quite nice:

> Dependiendo de los tiempos y aspectos que usamos, podemos indicar acciones relativas a otras:
>
> > Cuando cumplió cinco años…
> >
> > - … había viajado a otro país.
> >   <sup>(Viajó antes de cumplirlos)</sup>
> > - … hubo viajado a otro país.
> >   <sup>(Viajó justo antes de cumplirlos)</sup>
> > - … viajó a otro país.
> >   <sup>(Viajó poco después de cumplirlos)</sup>
> > - … iba a viajar a otro país.
> >   <sup>(Viajó, quizás, un tiempo después de cumplirlos)</sup>

If they are very brief — but still commentary — we can use subscript inline:

> Así que, es posible usar bien el subjuntivo, bien el indicativo, en cláusulas después del verbo decir:
>
> - Me dijo que yo estudiaba mucho. <sub>(descripción: indicativo)</sub>
> - Me dijo que yo estudiase/ra mucho. <sub>(orden: subjuntivo)</sub>

Brief information about things look better in subscript, IMO.  So if we're giving an answer for a beginner, and we want to mark who a pronoun or a verb is referring to, I recommend subscript (note the two sentences are in blockquote, because they are cast off and stand alone nicely).

> Once we have the sentence *Diego es muy guapo*, we can refer to him using the pronoun *él*:
>
> > Él<sub>(Diego)</sub> trabaja en casa.
>
> In fact, we don't even need the pronoun, because the verb lets us know:
>
> > Todos los días, se levanta<sub>(subj: Diego)</sub> a las ocho.

We should not, as a general rule, use the the tick marks `` to use preformatted text.  That is generally reserved for computer code, which won't come up often on this SE.  If we need to make a table, we can use the quadruple-space:

```
           NADAR (presente de indicativo)
-----------------------------------------------
        yo: NADO           nosotros/as: NADAMOS
    tú/vos: NADAS/NADÁS    vosotros/as: NADÁIS
él/ella/Vd: NADA          ellos/as/Vds: NADAN
```

For pronunciation, we should also follow general guidelines used in linguistics, although we shouldn't expect all users to know it, we can edit in and provide some more eye-readings if necessary.  Thus, we could say, there are three general ways to write pronunciation:

- **Phonemically** (transcripción fonológica)
  This will probably be the most common, and is done between /slashes/.  While in Spanish there are generally recognized archiphonemes such as /N/, /L/ and /R/, unless the question is such that they need to be recognized, it's best to avoid them.  The standard phonemes for Spanish are *a e i o u j w* (vowels/semivowels), and *b d f g k l ʎ m n ɲ p ɾ r s t ʧ x ʝ θ*.  We place a *'* in *front* of a syllable to represent that it carries the stress, and optionally a *.* to represent a syllable break (generally only if we want to strongly represent each individual syllable).  Several examples of phonemic transcriptions include */gug.le'ar/*, */kome'ɾi.a/*, */pronunθja'θjon/* ~ */pronunsja'sjon/*, */'ʧoʎo/* ~ */'ʧo.ʝo/*, */'toɾo 'roxo/*.
  This transcription isn't too hard, and can be easily fixed by moderators if necessary.
- **Phonetic (transcripción fonética)**
  This type of transcription describes the *actual* sounds that are produced, which means we can distinguish [b] (word initial) from [β̞] (intervocalically).  As you can tell, these transcriptions go in between square brackets [].  Stress is still marked with *'* and syllables if needed can be separated with *.*.  A word like *enviar* (/en.vi'ar/) could be phonetically rendered, depending on dialect, many different ways including [embi'ar], [em'bjar], [em'bjah] or [embi'a] (depending on how the R-final is pronounced and whether or not a hiatus is present).  There are a great number of symbols used for this type of transcription (see [Wiki's article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_AFI) on it) , but it will probably only be necessary to use in a handful of questions regarding regional differences or some other detailed question about pronunciation, and otherwise probably shouldn't be used too often.
- **Eye-spelling**
  This is something used in English a lot and to a lesser extent in Spanish.  It's so called because you just standard-like spelling to represent what you want to say.  For example, we might render "phonetics" as foh-NEH-ticks in English (with or without the hyphens).  In Spanish, this might be limited to adding in an accent mark where it's already clear something is stressed (and thus, *nadár*, *díje*, or *rió*), but might also replace some other letters like *s* (for *seseo dialectos*) or *t/z* (pensinsular D-final), y/i for diphthongs created from hiatuses (*envyár* or something), *j* for central Spain /sk/ (*ajco*), etc.  There aren't any hard or fast rules for these, and so while they can be useful, it's probably a good idea to also include a phonemic (between //) transcription as well, for example, "When we conjugate *pedir* (*pedír* /pe'dir/) in the present…" or something like that.

Comment: I like it in general! However, let me comment some parts I find a bit "ugly": having a huge header with _English_ and _Spanish_ gets too much space for the important matters. I tend to prefer having this header contain the title in the given language (with `###` so it is smaller). See [one example](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1790/1674). Also, I like using `<strike>` to cross out incorrect words.  Then, I found out SE uses the ASCII `→` for arrows, which comes handy instead of `->`.

Comment: I don't like strike: it's hard to read and also not common for languages (there are times to use it, but marking a general example as wrong isn't it, I don't think).  With ### is fine, I didn't know about it :-)  I agree on →, I was just being lazy and not looking up since it was more about the headers haha :-)

Comment: Cool! I specially like the usage of the subscript, to me it is the most readable form to show in-line translations and to clarify meanings. Still, the header _### English_ looks a bit ugly to me, so I by now will keep adding the title on the given language. Regarding the quadruple-space, it is worth explaining that it is the same as surrounding with the `<code>` ... `</code>` tag. Also, these four spaces can be achieved by selecting the text and pressing Ctrl+K. [See more on formatting](/help/formatting)...

Comment: guifa, and how do you mark pronunciation? `/gu-gle-AR/` is fine?

Comment: @fedorqui I added a bit.  I probably should keep it shorter (something like "use // for phonemic, [] for phonetic", and then make a separate meta article about the actual transcription) but I don't think we need use `code` markers, the slashes and brackets should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are some generally understood guidelines but there is really no canonical documentation about formatting like in stackoverflow.

The Spanish SE community is still too small to see a prevalent pattern of formatting in answers or questions.

Eventually though we will have to have some guidelines for this.

Some of the things I have seen so far as "tacit" rules are:

#### Definitions from the rae are quotes

> Hello I am a RAE definition

#### Words that need emphasis can be bold or in italic.

This is an *important* word.

#### Incorrect words can be striken-through.

This is an <s>incorrect</s> word.

---

And that is all that comes to mind right now. I will complete this answer if something else comes up though.

Comment: thanks! I took the liberty to changing your answer a little bit. I hope it still reflects what you wanted to say.

Comment: Related: [Indicating wrong sentences](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/122/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui Yes the community agreed on that point.

Comment: Mmm not sure what was the agreement, I see three options and different opinions

Comment: I would also say generally words-as-words also go in italics (and very short phrases).  Anything longer than 3-4 words probably needs to go in quotation marks or in a > quoteblock / list (if many examples).

Comment: @guifa maybe you can edit the answer to show this. This way the post can eventually be used as a reference for future users.