# Can we have a Spanish translation in "What is meta?"?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado

We have a beautiful page [What is "meta"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) with a good description about it. However, [it might be useful](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/how-should-we-format-text/2453?noredirect=1#comment3815_2453) to have it translated so its concept is understandable by everybody.

Could this happen?

Comment: I looked it over, and I decided my Spanish isn't up to the job.

Comment: Contamos ahora con la traducción de Spanish Stack Overflow: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Muy buena la traducción.  Donde dice "hecha un vistazo", pienso que debería ser "echa un vistazo".  Pero en todo caso, es mucho mejor de lo que esperaba.

Comment: @WalterMitty ¡ya tenemos la traducción! Está en [What's meta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras comentarlo con los moderadores [Jon Ericson](http://stackexchange.com/users/1083/jon-ericson) y [Tim Post](http://stackexchange.com/users/20808/tim-post), el primero ha tenido la amabilidad de añadir la sección [¿Qué es meta y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) que se tradujo para el sitio Spanish Stack Overflow.

Así, ahora disponemos de las dos versiones: en castellano y en inglés. Podéis verlo en:

[What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Desde aquí, ¡gracias a ambos!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [Edit] para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [help/on-topic]. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a website that introduces the concept of meta discussions, in Spanish.  It's about Wikimedia rather than Wikipedia, but it's related.

http://tecnologiaedu.uma.es/materiales/wiki/archivos/t1_wiki.pdf

If you scroll down to page 9, you'll see a brief paragraph about meta discussions.  It's highly possible that some of the terms are geek speak rendered in Spanish, rather than "real Spanish".

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this interesting information. Note, however, I am asking if the current meta description could be translated to Spanish, so a mere translation is enough. But it is a good point your link may provide some words to be used during the translation.

Comment: That was the idea.  Someone intending to translate the page into Spanish might get some benefit by reading this article first.   I guess I should have made that clear.