# Enlacemos las respuestas de otros usuarios si las mencionamos en nuestras publicaciones

Tags: discusión, formato

Al ser una comunidad maja y sin competividad entre las respuestas, es común que respondamos poniendo como referencia lo dicho por otro usuario. Es genial y contribuye a que las publicaciones sean más completas y dinámicas.

De vez en cuando, sin embargo, los nombres de usuario cambian. Uno puede darse cuenta en el momento y seguir haciendo la traducción mental (usuarioX ahora es usuarioY), pero ese conocimiento no lo tienen todos y seguramente no lo tendrán los usuarios que vengan después.

Es por ello que recomiendo que cuando en una publicación digamos *como dice el usuarioX*, añadamos un enlace a tal publicación. Eso nos protege ante cambios de nombre y ayuda enormemente a los usuarios que no están al corriente de los nombres habituales del sitio.

Caso práctico:

> Como dice usuarioX...

Entonces diríamos:

> Como dice [usuarioX](enlace a su respuesta)...

No recomiendo iniciar una edición masiva de publicaciones, pero sí sugiero que corrijamos los casos a medida que veamos publicaciones que *sufran* de este problema, aprovechando para hacer todo el resto de cosas que siempre hacemos: [corregir formato](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2440/1674), clarificar contenido, [enlazar debidamente](/help/referencing), añadir versión en inglés/castellano si queremos que sea [canónico](/q/2505/1674), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Es una buena idea. Como alternativa, aunque quedaría más impersonal, podríamos hacer uso de la pasiva refleja y establecer el siguiente formato:

> Como se dice/afirma/comenta/... en [título de la pregunta](enlace a la pregunta)...

O para respuestas:

> Como se dice/afirma/comenta/... en [esta respuesta](enlace a la respuesta) a la pregunta [título de la pregunta](enlace a la pregunta)...

De este modo ya quedaríamos totalmente a salvo de cambios de nombre de usuario, y aunque quede más impersonal, al pulsar en el enlace siempre se puede comprobar quién es el autor del texto enlazado.

Comment: Sí, exacto, la esencia es la misma: enlazar la respuesta de la que hablamos, para que el nexo sea a través del enlace y no del nombre de usuario.

Comment: Nótese por cierto que lo de `[título de la pregunta](enlace a la pregunta)` no es necesario, pues al poner `enlace a la pregunta` automáticamente se expande al título.